# Only use mtime comparison with rsync?

Tags: ssh, rsync, cp, timestamps

Is it possible to sync files via `rsync` and let `rsync` only compare mtime informations?

Or is there another tool for this job?

That means that such a tool only copies src to destination if the src is newer than the destination. Comparable to GNU `cp --update` - but also over ssh ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. `rsync` also has `--update`, but with it `rsync` still uses its delta-transfer algorithm in case the src is newer. `rsync` provides the `--whole-file` option to disable this algorithm. Thus,

```
$ rsync --update --whole-file ...
```

should have the effect that src files are only copied to the destination when they are newer. And only mtime checks should be used for this.

There are several reasons to avoid the delta-transfer algorithm for special use cases. Mainly performance reasons and perhaps transfer volume in very special cases.

To quote from the man-page:

> -W, --whole-file
>
> With this option rsync’s delta-transfer algorithm is not used and
>       the  whole  file  is  sent  as-is instead.  The transfer may be
>       faster if this option is used when the bandwidth between the
>       source and destination machines is higher than the bandwidth to
>       disk (especially when the "disk" is actually  a networked
>       filesystem).   This  is  the default when both the source and
>       destination are specified as local paths, but only if no
>       batch-writing option is in effect.

The case about networked filesystems should be the most common one.

Also, since the delta-transfer algorithm is a heuristic you can imagine files where the algorithm ends up transferring the whole file and just adds (time and space) overhead.

Comment: I don't understand why `--update` (`-u`) alone isn't enough.

Comment: If you want to get the exact same behavior as `cp --update`, you'd need to transfer the whole file. Although I know of no reason why you wouldn't want to speed-up your transfers.

Comment: @Gert, @Gilles: updated the answer and added a motivation for `--whole-file`.